# how i can make flexible to the count of *a items?

Tags: python

```
def LCM_M(*a):
    highest=max(a)
    value=highest
    while True:
            if highest%a[0]==0 and highest%a[1]==0 and highest%a[2]==0:
                return highest                
            else:
                highest+=value
                
print(LCM_M(8,6,16))
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `all`. `all` has the same benefit of using multiple `and` conditions, in that it short circuits.

```
def LCM_M(*a):
    highest=max(a)
    value=highest
    while True:
        if all(highest%i == 0 for i in a):
            return highest
        else:
            highest+=value
                
print(LCM_M(8,6,16))
print(LCM_M(2, 4, 6, 8))
```

Output

```
48
24
```

Comment: thanks alot it is very helpfull,(i m still crawling in python)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want your test to be

```py
if all(highest%val == 0 for val in a):
```

... rather than testing individual elements of a, iterate across them and test the suite of results.

Comment: I am sorry, how is this different from my answer?

Comment: It’s great minds thinking alike, but some of us typing more slowly.

Comment: :) In any case, you might want to rephrase it, "test the set" makes it sound like you have a `set` which you are not

Comment: I resolve never again to use my blasted phone to answer newish questions on this site. (Among other handicaps, in order to get back ticks I had to go to another answer and copy them from the edit window). And thanks for illustrating the ambiguity of the word “set”, which I will consider changing if I can find the edit button on this setup.